# How to Update properties of sharepoint 2013 feature

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a feature receiver for BCS model (Farm feature) and I am trying to update the value of a property `SiteUrl` dynamically in this receiver.

Below is the code:

```
properties.Definition.Properties["SiteUrl"].Value = "Some value";
properties.Feature.Properties.Update();
```

But I get the following error on the last line:

> Updating the properties of a feature definition is not supported.

Can anyone provide any inputs?